# Ways to limit/narrow the list

Tags: word-choice, transitivity

How to arrow/limit the text that comes after some broader meaning. 
For example:
Several models have been proposed in the field of mathematics and engineering. Now I want to limit my further discussion on engineering field neglect the other one. How to make a transition?

Comment: Those models specific to engineering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to distinguish between the two fields, you'll want to say "...in the **fields** of mathematics and engineering."

Along with JonLarby's suggestion of

> "Those models specific to engineering..." (i.e., the models that are only used in engineering)

you might say

> "The engineering models..." or "The models **corresponding to** (or **related to** or **associated with** or **typically used in**) engineering..." (i.e., the models that use engineering techniques or are well suited to engineering applications).

You might also begin the following sentence with

> Focusing our attention on the engineering models, we find that ...
>
> In the context of engineering, ...

but these choices all leave open the possibility that you will later discuss the mathematics-associated models. To eliminate this possibility in the reader's mind, you might say

> We restrict the scope of our discussion to the engineering models.
>
> Our discussion is limited to models used in an engineering context.
>
> Here, we discuss only the engineering models.

where the last option is simple, effective, and appropriate for a technical discussion.

Comment: Thank you! this is amazing and can be translated to many other cases in my writing.